# Индекс для колонок MYSQL . Нужны ли и какие?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте .

```
select * from table advert where advert.hide='show' and advert.end_putdate > 1481144400 order by advert.premium_adv DESC, advert.sort_time DESC limit 0 , 10
```

В базе 800тыс.объяв, 600 тыс. - активные.  Долго выбирает  объявления. Имеет ли смысл использовать индексы ? - если да, то для данной выборки, как правильно создать ?

на данный момент у меня стоят такие индексы

```
id_advert - primary

hide,premium_adv,premium_adv ,sort_time   -  составной
```

Генерация страницы : в первый раз загрузки от 3 до 9 секунд стала (была 20), последующая 0.2 сек.

Я делаю в базе explain по этому запросу  (выше) и получаю свои индексы и row 600 тыс.

Получается, что вместо 10 выбираются все ? Подскажите, чего я не  понимаю до конца ?

Спасибо !

Comment: Вероятно, потому что в индексе нет `end_putdate`?

Comment: ошибка в тексте .. Есть в  он, просто два раза дублировал `premium_adv,premium_adv`

Comment: Так поправьте текст, можно ведь.

Answer (score 0):

> Генерация страницы : в первый раз загрузки от 3 до 9 секунд стала (была 20), последующая 0.2 сек.

Это понятно - первый раз заполняется кэш.

> Имеет ли смысл использовать индексы ? - если да, то для данной выборки, как правильно создать ?

Да. Для ЭТОЙ выборки - составной *(hide, end_putdate[, другие поля])*. Сортировку по причине наличия условия по неравенству индексом ускорить уже не получится.

Сколько объявлений отбирает такой запрос без лимита? Насколько он кэшируемый?

Answer (score 0):

> Я делаю в базе explain по этому запросу (выше) и получаю свои индексы
>   и row 600 тыс. Получается, что вместо 10 выбираются все ? Подскажите,
>   чего я не понимаю до конца ?

Это происходит потому, что 10 записей отбираются из отсортированного списка. Т.е. сначала у вас считываются все записи удовлетворяющие условию, сортируются, а потом уже к ним применяется LIMIT. В такой ситуации стоит задуматься об внесении изменений в условия отбора.

> Имеет ли смысл использовать индексы ?

Однозначно да. Для этого запроса индекс на `advert.end_putdate` даст заметный прирост производительности.

Также имеет смысл посмотреть в сторону партиционирования по полю advert.hide, но это тема неоднозначная и потребует от вас некоторого количества исследований и тестов.